# How to call api in powerbi to get data?

Tags: api, powerbi, powerquery, invoke

I am a bit beginner of powerbi, I want to call api from power bi to get some data.

I tried to write this code but always return this error once I clicked invoke button
[image]

Here is the code that I used:

```
let
GetWorkItemIds = () =>
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://dev.azure.com/XXX/XXX/_apis/wit/workitems/13?api-version=7.0")),
    workItems = Source[workItems],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(workItems, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expand Ids" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id"}, {"Work Item Id"})
in
    #"Expand Ids"
in
    GetWorkItemIds
```

Anyone can give idea please. Thanks a lot

2nd try:

```
() =>
let body = [username = "", password = "xxxxxx"],
    Data = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://dev.azure.com/X/X/_apis/wit/workitems/13")),
    result = Record.Field(Data[result] {
        0
    }, "token")
in
result
```

this is my second try, it also return the same error as the picture above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation on the [API endpoint response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#workitem), it looks to me like you are treating the response erroneously. The endpoint does not return a list of work items, but a JSON representing one singular work item based on its ID - in your case `ID = 13`.

As you can see in the linked documentation, the response does not contain anything called `workItems`, which I suspect is causing your error.

However, I think your error stems from lack of **authentication**.

Comment: I update my code, but also return same error

Comment: Your updated code does not authenticate anything.